# Ways to implement time frames in Swift 2

Tags: swift, time, calendar, nsdate

Here is the cafeteria hours

```
Monday - Thursday: 10:30 am - 12:00 am
Friday: 10:30 am - 9:00 pm 
Saturday - Sunday: Closed
```

I am implementing a function that returns a status if the place is open or closed based on current time.
Is there an easier and more efficient way to implement such thing without dealing with complex "if" statement?

```
func displayStatusForBrandywine () -> String
    {
         let currentDateTime = NSDate()
        // get the user's calendar
        let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        // choose which date and time components are needed
        let requestedComponents: NSCalendarUnit = [
            NSCalendarUnit.Year,
            NSCalendarUnit.Month,
            NSCalendarUnit.Day,
            NSCalendarUnit.Hour,
            NSCalendarUnit.Minute,
            NSCalendarUnit.Weekday
        ]
        // get the components
        let dateTimeComponents = userCalendar.components(requestedComponents, fromDate: currentDateTime)
        var status: String = ""

        if ((dateTimeComponents.weekday >= 2 && dateTimeComponents.weekday <= 5) && (dateTimeComponents.hour >= 10 && dateTimeComponents.hour <= 23) && (dateTimeComponents.minute <= 59 && dateTimeComponents.hour != 0) || ((dateTimeComponents.weekday == 6 && dateTimeComponents.hour >= 10 && dateTimeComponents.minute >= 30 && dateTimeComponents.hour <= 21) || (dateTimeComponents.weekday == 6 && dateTimeComponents.hour >= 11 && (dateTimeComponents.hour <= 21 && dateTimeComponents.minute < 0))))
        {
            status = "Open"
        }
        else
        {
            status = "Closed"
        }
        return status
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun way to do it...

```
struct OpenPeriod {
    var day: Int
    var openTime: Double
    var closeTime: Double

    func isOpen(dateTime: NSDate) -> Bool {
        let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        // choose which date and time components are needed
        let requestedComponents: NSCalendarUnit = [
            NSCalendarUnit.Hour,
            NSCalendarUnit.Minute,
            NSCalendarUnit.Weekday
        ]
        // get the components
        let dateTimeComponents = userCalendar.components(requestedComponents, fromDate: dateTime)
        if dateTimeComponents.weekday != self.day { return false }
        let timeOfDay = Double(dateTimeComponents.hour) + Double(dateTimeComponents.minute) / 60
        return timeOfDay >= self.openTime && timeOfDay <= self.closeTime
    }
}

var openingTimes = [OpenPeriod]()
openingTimes.append(OpenPeriod(day: 2, openTime: 10.5, closeTime: 12))
openingTimes.append(OpenPeriod(day: 3, openTime: 10.5, closeTime: 12))
openingTimes.append(OpenPeriod(day: 4, openTime: 10.5, closeTime: 12))
openingTimes.append(OpenPeriod(day: 5, openTime: 10.5, closeTime: 21))

func open(dateTime: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return openingTimes.reduce(true, combine: { $0 && $1.isOpen(dateTime) })
}

open(NSDate()) ? "Open" : "Closed"
```

Comment: By the way, function reads the array in the wrong way. I tested it in the Playground and It will display "Open" only if one value in the array